# Open existing file or make a new one with different name

Tags: perl, file-io

In a Perl script, I need to open a specific file, but if that file does not open (is corrupted, etc.) then I need to make a new file with a new name. If I can't make that new file, I should just die out because something is obviously wrong. Here is pseudocode of what I want to do:

```
if (!(open my $testFile, q{>>}, "C:\foo\bar\log.csv")) {
    open my $testFile, q{>>}, "C:\foo\bar\log1.csv";
}
if (!$testFile) {
    die $!;
}
```

How can I do this "try-catch" type of behavior in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of the million ways to do it:

```
my $fh;
open $fh, '<', 'C:\foo\bar\log.csv' or open $fh, '<', 'C:\foo\bar\log1.csv' or die 'Can not  open any file!';
```

Comment: Interesting...never see "condition or condition or condition" before!